# How to a code a hazard perception exam

Tags: javascript, flash

I've been looking throughout the web to see examples on how hazard perception exams have been coded but to no avail. Could anyone inform me the key points on the coding of a hazard perception exam? Or if there are any similar examples on the web?

A a hazard perception exam is a compulsory exam in the UK as part to receive a driving license. It involves watching a video from the point of view of a driver and clicking the video if you notice a hazard. The exam records how many hazard you have noticed and will give you a score e.g. 40 out of 45. There's an example here: http://theory-test-online.co.uk/free-hazard-perception-test-demo.htm I'm asking to see how to record clicks targeted on a video. The clicks also have to hit in a certain time frame around the hazard to count as correct.

Comment: What is a hazard perception exam?  And, can you be more specific as to the specific problem you are stuck on?

Comment: @Brad It's a compulsory exam in the UK as part to receive a driving license. It involves watching a video from the point of view of a driver and clicking the video if you notice a hazard. The exam records how many hazard you have noticed and will give you a score e.g. 40 out of 45. There's an example here: http://www.theory-test-online.co.uk/free-hazard-perception-test-demo.htm       I'm asking to see how to record clicks targeted on a video. The clicks also have to hit in a certain time frame around the hazard to count as correct. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that is much clearer now.  You should add that information to your question directly for others to easily find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is both very general and very specific. It's general because your goal can be achieved in many ways, and specific because you ask about a very specific type of exam. Here is some info to get you started:

You can use [HTML5 video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) or something like [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) to play the video and control its position.

You can listen for click events using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) or [jQuery .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and on every click check the current video position and see if it is in one of the ranges when the click should appear or not and count the points accordingly (add a point when the user should click and subtract otherwise, making sure that you don't get more than 1 point for every hazard).

Counting the points could be challenging but here is how it can be done:

Let's say that you have an array of correct hazards start-stop intervals, together with info whether any of them was clicked or not, and a number of penalty points for clicks when there was no hazard:

```
var harards, penalties;

hazards = [
  {
    start: 1,
    stop: 2,
    passed: false
  },
  {
    start: 4,
    stop: 5,
    passed: false
  },
  {
    start: 8,
    stop: 10,
    passed: false
  }
];

penalties = 0;
```

(Of course for real data it will be more like: `start: 38.8, stop: 42.3` etc.) Now for every click you can check the video position and test it with something like this:

```
function testHazard(time) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < hazards.length; i++) {
    if (time >= hazards[i].start && time <= hazards[i].stop) {
      hazards[i].passed = true;
      return;
    }
  }
  penalties++;
}
```

It will mark every hazard as passed if the click was inside its duration time or increase the penalties otherwise.

Now counting points is simple:

```
function countPoints() {
  var i, points = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < hazards.length; i++) {
    if (hazards[i].passed) {
      points++;
    }
  }
  return (points - penalties);
}
```

See: [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kurufa/2/edit?js,output) on JS Bin.

One additional tip: you may want to use the [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown) event (or [jQuery .mousedown()](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)) instead of the click event to make it work nicely with double clicks etc. For example the [exam from your comment](http://www.theory-test-online.co.uk/free-hazard-perception-test-demo.htm) doesn't seem to handle double clicks and multiple clicks nicely and prints: "You responded to this clip in an unacceptable manner!" Also I'm not sure if that exam counts the clicks correctly. The code that I wrote above should work fine for any number of clicks and will just result in lower (or even negative) number of points when people click when they shouldn't, while counting any number of clicks during one hazard as one point.

Some useful resources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- http://api.jquery.com/category/events/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: when I tried to preview this script in the browser it shows the javascript alert "total points: -5, penalties: 5" and then when I click ok the video plays but with no response. Im not sure if it may be because of the onclick function I used or my html tags are wrong.  [code]<video controls autoplay video id="test"
   width="800" height="600" name="Video Name" src="test.mov"></video>
  <source src="test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>[/code] and for the script: [code]var vid = document.getElementById("test"); 
vid.onclick = countPoints;[/code]